# Screen Auto Rotation Fix on Dell 2 in 1 with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, laptop, screen, tablet, rotate

How can I make the screen on my Dell Inspiron 11 3000 series rotate automatically when I put it into tablet mode?